# Trying to add images to my Frame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jlabel

```
private void initialize() {
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 1071, 686);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 0, 0, 0));
    frame.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon("ship.png")));
    frame.getContentPane().add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon("ship.png")), ******);
}
```

So I thought my second last line would add the image to the frame, but it didn't. trying to work out how to use the last line to see if that will work. I can make GUI's in c# no problem, but thats more down to visual studio. Struggling with Java, I have installed window builder to make my life easier but I want to add a fair few images to make a grid onscreen and it doesn't appear to support images so I'm trying to do them manually.

Comment: Your problem is likely that you're not looking for the image where you think you're looking for it. Do you know where your images are in relation to the user directory? Find out. Print out: `System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.dir"));`

Comment: I usually don't need to add a full directory if I add it into the project. I'll try it out though!

Comment: It appears to point to /Users/alihassan/Dropbox/Uni/workspace/SD3 Coursework
Right where I placed my images

Comment: No, I didn't say to do that, just to find out where your file is relative to the user.dir. Better still, don't get the image as a file but rather as a resource.

Answer (score 0):

I got it with this

```
JLabel jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel1.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(("ship1.png"))); // NOI18N
    frame.getContentPane().add(jLabel1);
```

I actually installed netbeans just to get it to generate this for me as googling led me to many very different solutions

Comment: The only main difference I see is that your image file name is different. Where it was "ship.png", now it is "ship1.png"